# Dropzone adding custom element and custom listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

how can I add custom element and custom listener to dropzone. I added custom link to dropzone area and just a jquery click event, but it doesn't seem to work. When you click that link in dropzone area, it triggers file upload window. It's strange because, when you click on remove link, it respectively triggers remove event and doesn't trigger dropzone area.

This is how it looks on the website:

[image]

Thumbnails are some why cut, if you can tell me why is that, it'd be also nice :). But the main question, how to make "Set main image" link work(add this element and event to dropzone, not generally, that's my thoughts). Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Dropzone config.

```
dropz = new Dropzone('[data-form="announcement"]',
      paramName: 'image',
      acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .jpeg, .png',
      maxFilesize: 2,
      uploadMultiple: true
      autoProcessQueue: false
      parallelUploads: 100
      maxFiles: 10
      clickable: '.file-input'
      previewsContainer: '#preview-file'
      previewTemplate: document.querySelector('#previewTemplate').innerHTML
      init: ->
        myDropzone = this
        console.log(myDropzone.listeners)
        addedFile = false
        proccessedErrors = false
        existedFileCount = 0
        if page is 'PetsArea::AnnouncementsEdit'


          id = $('#announcement_id').val()
          $.ajax(
            method: 'GET'
            url: window.pets.globalVariables.urls.loadImages
            dataType: 'json'
            data:
              id: id
            success: (data) ->
              main_image_id = data['main_link']
              _.each(data['data'], (val) ->
                myDropzone.emit('addedfile', val)
                myDropzone.emit('thumbnail', val, val['url'])
                myDropzone.emit('success', val)
                myDropzone.emit('complete', val)
                myDropzone.files.push(val)
              )
          )

          new_clickable = $('[data-image="main"]')[0]
          new_listener = $.extend({}, myDropzone.listeners[myDropzone.listeners.length - 1])
          new_listener.element = new_clickable
          myDropzone.clickableElements.push(new_clickable)
          myDropzone.listeners.push(new_listener)
          myDropzone.disable()
          myDropzone.enable()

        this.on('addedfile', (file) =>
          addedFile = true
          proccessedErrors = false
          existedFileCount += 1 if file['url']
          if file['id'] is main_image_id
            preview = $('.dz-preview:last-child')
            preview.find('a').remove()
            preview.append(
              '<span data-main="image"><i class="fa fa-crosshairs"></i> Main image</span>'
            )
          else if file['id']
            preview = $('.dz-preview:last-child')
            preview.find('[data-image="main"]').attr('id', "#{file['id']}")
            preview.find('a.dz-remove').attr('id', "#{file['id']}")


          if this.files.length > 10
            this.removeFile(file)
        )

        this.element.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', (e) =>
          return unless addedFile and this.files.length > existedFileCount
          form.data('formValidation').validate()
          return unless form.data('formValidation').isValid()
          e.preventDefault()
          e.stopPropagation()
          myDropzone.processQueue()
        )

        this.on('successmultiple', (record, reply) ->
          window.location.href = reply['url']
        )

        this.on('error', (record, reply) ->
          unless proccessedErrors and !addedFile
            myDropzone.removeAllFiles()
            addedFile = false
            proccessedErrors = true
            window.location.reload();
        )
      removedfile: (file) ->
        if file['url']
          id = file['ad-id']
          photoId = file['photo-id']
          image_row = $(this).closest('[data-delete="block"]')
          $.ajax(
            method: 'POST'
            url: window.pets.globalVariables.urls.editPhotoDelete
            data:
              id: id
              photo_id: photoId
            success: (data) ->
              $(file['previewElement']).fadeOut('fast')
          )
        else
          $(file['previewElement']).fadeOut('fast')
    )
```

External link:

```
 $('[data-image="main"]').click ->
      e.preventDefault()
      e.stopPropagation()
      id = $(this).attr('id')
      prev_main_image = $("[data-image='main'] a##{main_image_id}").closest('.dz-preview')
      prev_main_image.find('[data-image="main"]').remove()
      prev_main_image.append('<a class="dz-remove" href="javascript:undefined" data-dz-remove><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Remove file</a> +' +
          '<a data-image="main"><i class="fa fa-crosshairs main-image"></i> Set main image</a>')

      cur_main_image = $("[data-image='main'] a##{id}").closest('.dz-preview')
      cur_main_image.find('a').remove()
      cur_main_image.append('<span><i class="fa fa-crosshairs"></i> Main image</span>')
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the behavior you are describing is due to propagation, but some code would help to answer your question.

Comment: Ok, please see edit.